# hosting and Code sharing strategy for multiple react frontends

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm planning to create a bunch of (2 to 3) ReactJS frontends that all primarily interact with the same existing Ruby on Rails API. Each frontend will appear on a different domain, but will use the same graphic design system and UI. Because of this I imagine that they will be sharing a lot of code.

How would you recommend organizing the code for such a project? And also how would you deploy it?

#### Code sharing

In my research I found the solution of creating a node package that just contains the shared components/code. My concern there is that then the developer (me) would have to be constantly bouncing from the module's repo to the repo for each site.

I also noticed [bit](https://bit.dev/) but wondering if I want to be so dependent on a proprietary service.

These frontend sites don't really need to be completely isolated from each other in different repositories—even though they are on different domains, you could almost think of them as different sections of the same site, in the sense that they are closely related.

#### Deployment

If, for example, all this code is kept in the same npm project, then it's conceivable that when deploying, several build scripts could build each frontend and then push each build to a CDN. Would that be a good strategy?

Comment: Have you heard of yarn workspaces? https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/

Comment: And netlify for hosting https://www.netlify.com/